# IdentityServer4 Core 3.1 Error Reading Message LogoutMessage

Tags: identityserver4

On my Logout Post method I am seeing

***Exception Reading protected message
JSON Value could not be converted to IdentityServer4.Models.LogoutMessage. Path: Line 0, BytePos 170***

It's IS4.0.2 running on Core 3.1.5

Any immediate thoughts as to what is causing this?  Upgraded from 3 to 4 and it started. Seems to be working however!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it the SeriLog logging, reflecting the parameter

Log.Verbose("model={@LogoutInputModel}", model);

When verbose logging on, no error and no output
When verbose logging off, error